# How to bind a Map<String, String> using form values

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a form that contains a new select HTML item for each `device` related with the `profile` that I'm editing. Each select is loaded with a `privileges` enumerated that will assign a value to that `device` for the current `profile`.  When I send the form to update all the devices of this profile at the same time, my PUT request contains the following elements:

```
devices[16]: DEFAULT
devices[36]: DEFAULT
devices[37]: DISABLED
devices[39]: DEFAULT
```

(Also, I've tried it using Strings)

```
devices["aa"]: DEFAULT
devices["bb"]: DEFAULT
devices["cc"]: DISABLED
devices["dd"]: DEFAULT
```

My controller method looks like:

```
@PutMapping( name = "update" )
public ModelAndView update( @Valid @ModelAttribute Profile profile, 
      @RequestParam("devices") Map<String, String> interfacePrivileges, 
      BindingResult result, Model model ){

[...]

}
```

When I execute the code above seems that Spring expects a `devices` parameter...

As the Spring documentation sais

*account[COMPANYNAME] - Indicates the value of the map entry indexed by
the key COMPANYNAME of the Map property account*

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conventions

Why is not binding correctly my request?

Regards,

Comment: "account[2] Indicates the third element of the indexed property account. Indexed properties can be of type array, list or other naturally ordered collection"

Comment: Check the Spring MVC documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conventions Seems like is possible to bind a Map too, isn't it?

Comment: If you weren't using integer indices maybe. Also this isn't actually the MVC documentation.

Comment: I also try it using Strings in the request instead of Integers like devices["identifier"]: DEFAULT.. and the same result appears.

Comment: If you put `@RequestParam` on a `Map<String, String>` it thinks you're trying to bind all the parameters.

Comment: Seems like when an @RequestParam annotation is used on a Map<String, String> or MultiValueMap<String, String> argument, the map is populated with all request parameters. See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam